# Ubuntu Apache 10 second timeout

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, timeout

I'm debugging an API I'm building using netcat to send raw HTTP requests. The thing is that Apache closes the connection after 10 seconds, giving me very little time to type. I know that I could pipe a file to nc, or use any other workaround, but I'd like it to work as it's supposed to.

The Timeout directive in apache2.conf is at its default of 300 seconds, KeetAliveTimeout at 15 seconds. Where could this 10 second timeout possibly be defined? I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 Desktop.

Thanks,

Andreas

Comment: Do you have any firewall between the box where you're running the netcat and the Apache box? I've seen cases in which the "idle timeout" in the firewall was set too low.

Comment: I don't think I do, when I sniff it with Wireshark it's the process on port 80 (Apache) that closes the connection. I run both client and server on the same box at the moment, so I imagine Wireshark would pick up any intermediaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like mod_reqtimeout needs some tweaking.  Take a look at the docs for [mod_reqtimeout](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html)

On ubuntu 10.04, I believe you will find the configuration in:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/reqtimeout.conf
```